# PackageMaker installs nothing

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, package-managers

i have a problem, which is exactly as here http://compgroups.net/comp.sys.mac.apps/PackageMaker-not-installing-my-app (no solution is offered)

simply said, with PackageMaker i create an installer, which should just copy the .app inside /Applications

**all goes well, the installer has the apropriate size of 150MB, the install starts, iam promped for the install location and admin password, i click install, progress shows up and a window that installation was successfull, but when i look at the Applications, or the custom folder specified, its nothing there**

i tryed the PackageManager from Xcode 3 and also 4, but the result is the same, i also tryed to set the file permission for everybody, so they are world writable, but no success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you testing the installer on the same machine where you are building the installer? If you've set the "Allow Relocation" box a install will simply overwrite your already existing app you used for packaging instead of installing to /Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the package just to move the app inside /Applications.

Just zip your app bundle so that it becomes `YourApp.app.zip`, which is a perfectly acceptable way to distribute your app. Then the user can place the app bundle (after unpacking the zip) wherever the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Include root in package" enabled for the package's contents?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924049/what-does-packagemakers-include-root-in-package-option-actually-do/6928683#6928683) for an explanation of what it does and why you probably need it.